# access lists not working on n3k

Tags: nx-os

i have a n3k-c3064pq-10gx with version 7.0(3)I7(9) Bios:version 4.5.0 version and i have 2x 10G SFP+ (LACP) from my carrier and here is my switch config :
SWT(config-acl)# show ip access-lists uplink-acl

```
IP access list uplink-acl
        statistics per-entry
        10 permit ip x.x.x.x/32 any [match=0]
        20 permit ip y.y.y.y/28 any [match=0]
        30 permit ip z.z.z.z/32 any [match=0]
        40 deny tcp any any eq bgp [match=8]
        70 deny udp any any eq ntp [match=3]
        80 permit ip any any [match=2401]
SWT(config-acl)# sh run int po110

!Command: show running-config interface port-channel110
!Running configuration last done at: Fri Dec 25 12:00:34 2020
!Time: Fri Dec 25 12:02:15 2020

version 7.0(3)I7(9) Bios:version 4.5.0

interface port-channel110
  description UPLINK
  no switchport
  ip access-group uplink-acl in
  no ip redirects
  ip address 1.2.3.4/29
```

when i telnet to TCP 179 from outside of my network it shows the packets has been matched with rule id 40 but from the internet it shows TCP 179 is open, also i have add ip access-list match-local-traffic in global config,
any idea or help?
Thanky ou.

Comment: Logically, that should work. However, you may need to edit the control-plane-policy (CoPP) to make it work -- the nexus platform is weird.

Comment: any working sample, that how can i do this in CoPP ? because i have read CoPP for n3k it just only support PPS rate limiting not drop or permit

Comment: i have set 1.2.3.4/29 on int po110 and its also strange when i add "5 deny ip any 1.2.3.4/32" still i can telnet to tcp 179 from the internet! with this rule i have blocked everything totally! i do not want why does it work! any idea?